# Select polygons which do not contain points

Tags: arcmap, polygon, point, intersection

I am able to use the intersect tool to find polygons which overlap with points however I would like to find polygons which do not overlap with any points.

I think the [Symmetrical Difference Tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/symmetrical-difference.htm) would be an appropriate tool to do so, but I do not have the pro license to use it. I cannot use the Union tool either as it does not accept points as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options I can think of off hand.

1

You could use the select by location tool, and select all polygons that intersect the points. Then reverse the selection in the attribute table, thereby switching the selection from those that have points within them, to those that do not interact with the points at all.

2

You could run the spatial join tool and select all polygons that have a join count of 0.